# How to preserve server change timestamps on files get using GET in TFS?

Tags: tfs, version

I am using workspace.get() in TFS 2013 environment. It works perfectly, however, the timestamps on files downloaded are set to current timestamp.

Is there a way to get files and set the file timestamps to either the checkin time or actual file edit time on server?

I tried to look for answers on Google as well as Stackoverflow. The closest thing I found was a thread on MSDN which didn't have a conclusive answer.

Hopefully, someone can provide a quick answer to this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I need to write a merge with another repository and I need to copy files to another repo (RTC) workspace. RTC workspace preserves the file timestamps. I will need to merge depending on check in date in TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after searching through the internet and Microsoft document, I was able to create workspace with above property with following code:

```
$tfsServer = Get-TfsServer -Name $props.tfsURI -Credential $tfsRepoCredentials
$structureService = $tfsServer.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ICommonStructureService")
$versionControlService = $tfsServer.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer")

$workSpaceName = $env:USERNAME "-"+ $patchNumber

$wsParams = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionCotrol.Client.CreateWorkspaceParameters -ArgumentList $workSpaceName
$wsParams.WorkspaceOptions = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.WorkspaceOptions]::SetFileTimeToCheckin

$versionControlService.CreateWorkspace($wsParams)
```

The answers in the question [Automating workspace creation in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281464/automating-workspace-creation-in-team-foundation-server) provided helpful information on how to set workspace options.

Thanks to @Andy for help.

Answer (score 2):

By default TFS will write file times to the "**current**" time when you retrieved the files from remote repository. This is the default behavior of most version control tools and generally considered safe.

> Setting time to the remote time can have negative consequences in many
>   scenarios. For example, make will scan for files newer than the last
>   build time. Setting file times to the server's time can impact the
>   ability to determine which files have changed since the last build.

However, if you want to get files and set the file timestamps to the **checkin** time,  you can edit the specific **Workspace** by setting "**File Time**" to "**Checkin**":

```
Manage Workspaces... -> Select the specific workspace -> Edit -> Advanced -> File Time - Checkin
```

Please note below things (See [How do I choose advanced workspace options?](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=vsts#q-how-do-i-choose-advanced-workspace-options) for details.
) :

> **File Time:**
>
> - Choose **Checkin** if you want the date and time stamp of each file to generally match the stamp of the changeset of the version in your
>     workspace. A few issues and exceptions are:
>
>   - When you modify the local file, the date and time stamp will match the date and time when you modified the file.
>   - This feature is available only if you are using Visual Studio 2012 or later and Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 or later.
>   - **The setting does not apply to folders, unless there is a pending add or delete operation to a file contained by the folder.**
>   - You might not be able to build your code project incrementally. Instead, you will have to rebuild).
> - Choose **Current** if you want the date and time stamp to match the date and time when you last modified the local file. For example, a
>     team member checked in the latest change to the file on Monday. On
>     Tuesday, you perform a get operation to update the file. The date and
>     time stamp is set to Tuesday.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas on how to set this property with TFS API? We are creating workspace in the script and getting files in the same script.

Comment: @sohail I cannot find the method to set the `FileTime` property when create a workspace with the API, see [Workspace Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb171828(v%3dvs.120))

Comment: the API lists workspaceoptions as part of versioning server but there is no example on how to use the Enum associated with options.

Comment: Thank you. I will see if we can use that workaround. The workspace creation is part of a larger script that needs to be fully automated so adding a manual step in the middle might be challenging.

Comment: I was hoping to use this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh717631%28v%3dvs.120%29 with the workspace option parameter set to appropriate value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh718134%28v%3dvs.120%29 API has both get and set. Do you if someone can provide a sample to use these API call